# Listing and shuffling a deck of cards in C

Tags: c

My project is to develop a program using structures, enumerations, and strings to first list a deck of cards by suit and rank in 13 rows and 4 columns and then shuffle them and output the random deck in the same fashion.  This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    char suit;
    char rank[10];

}CARDS;

int main(void)
{
  char str[] = {"Clubs Hearts Diamonds Spades"};
  CARDS deck[52];

  int i;
  int count = 0;
  int num = 1;

  for(i=0; i<52; i++)
  {
   deck[i].suit=str[count];

    //Assigning the card number with switch statement
    switch(num)
    {
        case 1: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "ACE");
            break;
        case 2: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "Deuce");
            break;
        case 3: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "3");
            break;
        case 4: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "4");
            break;
        case 5: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "5");
            break;
        case 6: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "6");
            break;
        case 7: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "7");
            break;
        case 8: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "8");
            break;
        case 9: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "9");
            break;
        case 10: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "10");
            break;
        case 11: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "Jack");
            break;
        case 12: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "Queen");
            break;
        case 13: strcpy(deck[i].rank, "King");
            break;
    }//end switch

    num++;

    //If statement for assigning numbers
    if((i+1)%13==0)
    {
        count++;
        num = 1;
    }//end if

}//end for

//Local Statements
printf("Before Shuffling:\n\n");

for(i=0; i<=52; i++)
{
    printf("%s %c", deck[i].rank, deck[i].suit);
   printf(" ");
    if(count < 3)
        count++;
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        count = 0;
    }//end else
}//end for
return 0;
}
```

I have been unsuccessful so far with getting the right order of things and my suits won't print out the entire word.  This is just the beginning of me trying to get the cards listed in order.  I also know that I have not used any enumerations.  Not sure what to do there.  Please help!

Comment: The statement `for(i=0; i<=52; i++)` is wrong and you will access `deck[52]`, which must not be accessed.

Comment: so what should I be accessing?  I also know I think I need to sue an array to list the items.

Comment: `const char *str[] = {"Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades"};`

Comment: Only `deck[0]` to `deck[51]` are available because you declared as `CARDS deck[52];`

Comment: You might also consider nested `for` loops: `for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; ++suit) { for (int num = 0; num < 13; ++num) {...}}`

Comment: @DavidHouse you only need cards with 52 values `0..51`. You can obtain the suit with `card / 13` and its rank with `card % 13`. Then convert for human consumption at the point of output. For example, having corrected `char str[] = {"Clubs Hearts Diamonds Spades"};` to `char *suitname[] = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};` the suit name will be `printf("%s", suitname[card / 13]);`.

Comment: `printf("%c"...` only prints one character. You need `%s` for strings.

Comment: @DavidHouse, yes, integers are ideal for cards, but if you order them 2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,...A,A,A,A, then you can get suit and rank without teh expensive divide-by-13, and you can even compare by rank without separating rank/suit at all. Much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

- You stored only one character to the structure, so it is natural that the entire words for suits aren't printed.
- You shoudld use arrays of `const char*` for enumrating names of suits and ranks.
- Avoid off-by-one error: the loop condition `i<=52` in the second `for` loop is wrong.
- You should initialize `count` before entering the second loop.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    char suit[10];
    char rank[10];

}CARDS;

int main(void)
{
  const char* suit_names[] = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
  const char* rank_names[] = {"ACE", "Deuce", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
      "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
  CARDS deck[52];

  int i;
  int count = 0;
  int num = 1;

  for(i=0; i<52; i++)
  {
    strcpy(deck[i].suit, suit_names[count]);

    //Assigning the card number
    strcpy(deck[i].rank, rank_names[num - 1]);

    num++;

    //If statement for assigning numbers
    if((i+1)%13==0)
    {
      count++;
      num = 1;
    }//end if

  }//end for

  printf("Before Shuffling:\n\n");

  count = 0;
  for(i=0; i<52; i++)
  {
    printf("%s %s ", deck[i].rank, deck[i].suit);
    if(count < 3)
      count++;
    else
    {
      printf("\n");
      count = 0;
    }//end else
  }//end for
  return 0;
}
```

Then, introduce enumerates in some means and implement shuffle.

Comment: Thank you all for you input!  I will take at look and see what happens.  Would this be possible to list with an array:  like ary[13][4]; ??

Comment: @DavidHouse I didn't understand what you are saying well, but it should be possible.

Comment: My output is not listed in nice columns and rows so I was wondering if there was a way to list it as a matrix?  Does that make sense?

Comment: You have missed out "10" in `rank_names[]`, so when you index by 12 (the King) you'll get undefined behaviour. Note too that the "3" card is indexed with `rank_names[2]`, a trap for the unwary.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, added `"10"`.

Comment: Any advice on how to make this look nice in Rows and Columns?  I have it in the right format with suit and rank, but it looks quite messy.